# Custom slf4j logger interface

Tags: java, interface, slf4j

I would like to be able to enable/disable logging on instance level of some Java classes during runtime.

Obviously, I could have a class attribute "logEnabled" and then do

```
if (logEnabled) {   
  logger.debug("some info {}", someParameter);
}
```

But for readability I would prefer to customize the slf4j interface so I could do:

```
logger.debug(logEnabled, "some info {}", someParameter);
```

Should I simply wrap the Logger class in a custom class or is there some better way to do this? Performance is critical for my application so I don't want to add any extra copying of parameters.

Comment: Why are you wanting to deal with `logEnabled` manually? Unless `someParameter` is actually *calculated* for the log message, it's essentially free to copy it (and the JIT will probably remove it anyway eventually).

Comment: Both logEnabled and someParameter will change during runtime and they will change differently for different instances of the same Java class that calls logger.debug.

Comment: I will have a large number of instances of objects and I want to selectively be able to enable logging on specific instances during runtime.

Comment: Logback configuration file is powerful enough to handle this outside your code

Comment: Currently my `logger` is a an application-wide singleton. Would it be ok to have each instance of a class with many instances (tens of thousands) retrive its own logger by `LoggerFactory.getLogger()`? I just assumed the memory overhead would be too high.

But even if I did that I don't see how this could be completely handled outside my code. I want to be able to connect to an admin interface on my application and issue a command like "enable logging on objectInsance=XXXXX".

Comment: Scratch the last part of my comment above. If it would be ok to have one logger for each object instance I do see how it would solve my problem nicely.

Comment: If having tens of thousands of instances of your class is not already a problem, why do you think adding a separate `Logger` instance to each one would be?  It does sound like you want to use `LoggerFactory.getLogger()` to get a different `Logger` for each instance.  Then your logging line above will reduce to `logger.debug("some info {}", someParameter);` and you can let the `Logger` itself handle those debug messages as you want.

Comment: Thanks palimpsestor, I'll go with that approach. I incorrectly thought a Logger instance had a quite big system footprint.